# C# interprets SQL variables as MySQLParameters - How do i use SQL variables in C# code?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

i like to insert some values in an SQL-Database. Before that i want to set a variable in the database.

```
command.CommandText = "SET @lastid := 0;";
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO order(surname, note) VALUES (@surname, @note);";
command.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM order INTO @lastid;";

command.Prepare();
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", "Myname");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@note", textBoxAuftragNotiz.Text);
//command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastid", "100");
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**Visual Studio throws me the following error:
An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''@lastid' at line 1**

It seems that the compiler tries to use the internal @lastid Parameter instead of sending it to the database and executing it in SQL.

When uncommenting the following it works!
//command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastid", "100");

Comment: The only SQL you're executing is `SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM order INTO @lastid;`.  I think you meant to concatenate your 3 strings

Comment: Sorry @CharlesMager i thought that might be an issue.